# Lualatex and pdflatex missing with Tex Live 2018 minimum installation on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: pdftex, luatex, texlive, ubuntu, texlive-2018

I just installed Tex Live 2018 with the minimum scheme on Ubuntu 18.04. Apparently, this minimal scheme does not include applications like `lualatex` and `pdflatex` in `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux`. I, unfortunately, cannot seem to find which package I should install with `tlmgr` to obtain them.

How do I install them?

Comment: What exactly did you install? Ubuntus TexLive or the upstream TeXLive?

Comment: If you use the texlive installer, enter the `set installation collections` menu and select `LuaTeX packages` and `LaTeX recommended packages`

Comment: @daleif I downloaded http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz and ran `install-tl`.

Comment: @blub Ok clear. Do I understand correctly that these programs cannot be installed by means of `tlmgr`?

Comment: @Adriaan They are installed with almost all collections: which one did you use? The binary packages are called things like `latex-bin`

Comment: pdflatex is just a symbolic link to pdftex, did that really not get made?

Comment: If you installed the minimal scheme, you only get the plain format as it clearly stated in the installer. You probably want the `basic` scheme, or just install everything like everyone else. Note that `basic` probably does not include `lualatex`

Comment: @JosephWright I installed the minimal scheme.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle No it's not in the `bin` directory when you install the minimal scheme.

Comment: OK I always install everything:-) I suppose you get what you ask for then, minimally you could just use plain tex.

Comment: @Adriaan Have your tried `tlmgr install latex-bin`? Assuming you have pdfTeX/LuaTeX themselves installed, that should do it.

Comment: @JosephWright Setting the scheme to the option ` d [X] basic scheme (plain and latex)` solved the issue: `lualatex` and `pdflatex` are present in `/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux`. So I don't know if `tlmgr install latex-bin` also solves the issue. Perhaps I'll try it later with a virtual machine and see if it also solves this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the description of the installed scheme:

```
$ tlmgr info scheme-minimal
package:     scheme-minimal
category:    Scheme
shortdesc:   minimal scheme (plain only)
longdesc:    This is the minimal TeX Live scheme, with support for only plain TeX. (No LaTeX macros.)  LuaTeX is included because Lua scripts are used in TeX Live infrastructure.  This scheme corresponds exactly to collection-basic.
installed:   Yes
revision:    13822
sizes:       65425k
relocatable: Yes
```

It tells you that it is collection-basic. Looking at that info again

```
$ tlmgr info collection-basic
package:     collection-basic
category:    Collection
shortdesc:   Essential programs and files
longdesc:    These files are regarded as basic for any TeX system, covering plain TeX macros, Computer Modern fonts, and configuration for common drivers; no LaTeX.
installed:   Yes
revision:    45851
sizes:       65425k
relocatable: No
depends:
    texlive.infra
    amsfonts
    bibtex
    cm
    dvipdfmx
    dvips
    enctex
    etex
    etex-pkg
    glyphlist
    graphics-def
    gsftopk
    hyph-utf8
    hyphen-base
    ifluatex
    ifxetex
    knuth-lib
    knuth-local
    kpathsea
    lua-alt-getopt
    luatex
    makeindex
    metafont
    mflogo
    mfware
    pdftex
    plain
    tetex
    tex
    tex-ini-files
    texlive-common
    texlive-docindex
    texlive-en
    texlive-msg-translations
    texlive-scripts
    unicode-data
    updmap-map
    xdvi
```

You get the list of included packages, which shows nothing related to latex whatsoever.

I recommend installing `scheme-medium` to get a reasonable selection.