# Minimal installation to get lualatex (via tlmgr)

Tags: luatex, texlive, tlmgr

I'd liked to be able to run `lualatex` with a minimal TeX Live installation using `tlmgr`.

I've tried to start installing `scheme-minimal` but then cannot find what I should add to have the `lualatex` binary.

I've already added a number of individual packages (not especially related to LuaLateX) plus `collection-luatex` and `lualatex-math`. I thought maybe one of these two would come with `lualatex` as a dependency.

I've checked the `$PATH` is correct and also looked for the binary, but it's nowhere to be found, I only get directories:

```
# find / -name lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/source/lualatex
#
```

`luatex` binary got installed, though.

I've already seen that [installing scheme-medium](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/450643/81138) should solve the problem, but I'd really liked to get the minimal installation size: I'm automating this install along several other things on a server and the minimal size for what is strictly required is important. If there's no other way than installing `scheme-medium`, then I'll do it, but I do hope there is another way.

I've been browsing [CTAN website](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/) in vain and been doing a lot of `tlmgr info --list collection-something` and other `tlmgr info --list package-that-looks-related` but can't find the right collection or package. Where is it hidden?

(I don't think this is relevant, but this is all hosted in fresh up-to-date FreeBSD 12.1 jail)

Comment: If you want small, you have to take a scheme and add individual packages ...

Comment: @JosephWright That's what I try to do starting with `scheme-minimal`, but which package would then bring `lualatex` binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start from `scheme-minimal`, you will need to add at least `latex-bin`. This installs LaTeX and the necessary structures to do format-building. Without other packages, this only covers `lualatex` and `pdflatex`: you'd have to add `xetex` for `xelatex`, for example.

---

Dependencies in TeX Live are not 'hard': there is not a strict list of dependencies for every package going all the way down to `scheme-infra-only`. In particular, there is an assumption that all LaTeX packages depend implicitly on having LaTeX installed. That happens automatically with `scheme-small` but not `scheme-minimal`.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much, it worked fine! I just wonder how I could have found out by myself. I cannot even find `latex-bin` on CTAN.