# How do I install TeX Live on GNU/Linux without installing every package?

Tags: texlive, installing, linux

Following the [quickinstall instructions](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)
and running `perl install-tl`
begins downloading all 4000+ CTAN packages.
I've tried this on both Arch and Debian GNU/Linux.

Is there a way I can get a minimal installation of TeX Live
(without using the system package manager
so that I can still use `tlmgr`)?

Comment: there is a link to the full instructions on that page, see the `scheme` option which defaults to `full` but you can select smaller schemes

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Follow the installer. In the process of terminal interaction you can choose a scheme.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/547708/minimal-installation-to-get-lualatex-via-tlmgr/547712#547712 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554285/installing-just-tex/554338#554338 contain some ideas: do they help?

Comment: Yes! Thank you all for the help!